# ¿Alguna forma de envíar correos por Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook

Este es el problema:

Estoy realizando un proyecto, en una empresa en la que estoy de "prácticas" como becario y tal, la cosa es que me han encomendado un proyecto, para revisar ciertas cosas y demás, lo que yo quería era saber si mediante C# hay alguna forma de enviar correos por outlook, si es así, agradecería si me echáis una mano diciéndome que clases usar o que librerías.

Gracias.

Creo que el outlook está configurado como POP3, fui capaz de hacerlo por SMTP, más o menos...

Comment: Hola Aritz. Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Has de mostrar lo intentado, y los errores o problemas encontrados que te impiden hacer lo que pides. Mira [ask] y [mcve]. La pregunta de "qué clases o librerias" se considera *basado en opiniones*. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta función recibe como parámetros la dirección, el campo asunto, y el contenido principal. Podemos usar HTML para dar formato al contenido del email, o bien usar texto plano.

```
public static Boolean SendEmailWithOutlook(string mailDirection, string mailSubject, string mainContent)
{
    try
    {
        var oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        var f = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        var mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = mailSubject;
        mailItem.HTMLBody = mailContent;
        mailItem.To = mailDirection;
        mailItem.Send();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)                           
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
    }
    return true;
}
```

Es un código sencillo. Simplemente creamos un objeto de aplicación Outlook y usamos este para crear un nuevo email. Luego asignamos la dirección, asunto y contenido, y finalmente procedemos a su envío.

USO DE LA FUNCIÓN

A continuación un ejemplo directamente desde la función Main.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    string mailDirection = "ejemplo@ejemplo.com";
    string mailSubject = "Subject test";

    string mainContent;
    mainContent = "Mensaje de prueba";
    mainContent += "<br>" + "Otra línea";
    mainContent += "<br>" + "Otra línea";

    SendEmailWithOutlook(mailDirection, mailSubject, mailContent);
}
```

Simplemente creamos cadenas de texto con los campos necesarios, y empleamos nuestra función para realizar el envío.

[Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff865634.aspx) encontraras otros ejemplos

Comment: Me la guardo, para futuras ocasiones, gracias por responder,al final hemos cambiado el planteamiento del problema .

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el servicio de SMTP para enviar mail

[POP and IMAP email settings for Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-email-settings-for-Outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353)

si seleccionas del combo `outlook` veras los datos

```
SMTP outgoing server:    smtp-mail.outlook.com
SMTP port:    587
```

Esto es lo que deberias utilizar en la clase [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Quedando algo como ser

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(From, to, title, content);

client.Send(message);
```